# Training with Dataset API and numpy array yields completely different results

Tags: tensorflow, validation, dataset, tensorflow2.0, pipeline

I have a CNN regression model and feature comes in `(2000, 3000, 1)` shape, where 2000 is total number of samples with each being a (3000, 1) 1D array. Batch size is 8, 20% of the full dataset is used for validation.

However, zip feature and label into `tf.data.Dataset` gives **completely different** scores from feeding numpy arrays directly in.

#### The `tf.data.Dataset` code looks like:

```
# Load features and labels
features = np.array(features)  # shape is (2000, 3000, 1)  
labels = np.array(labels)  # shape is (2000,)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features, labels))
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=2000)
dataset = dataset.batch(8)

train_dataset = dataset.take(200)
val_dataset = dataset.skip(200)

# Training model
model.fit(train_dataset, validation_data=val_dataset,
          batch_size=8, epochs=1000)
```

#### The numpy code looks like:

```
# Load features and labels
features = np.array(features)  # exactly the same as previous
labels = np.array(labels)  # exactly the same as previous

# Training model
model.fit(x=features, y=labels, shuffle=True, validation_split=0.2,
          batch_size=8, epochs=1000)
```

#### Except for this, other code is exactly the same, for example

```
# Set global random seed
tf.random.set_seed(0)
np.random.seed(0)

# No preprocessing of feature at all    

# Load model (exactly the same)
model = load_model()

# Compile model
model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
    loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
    metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.mean_absolute_error, ],
)
```

The former method via tf.data.Dataset API yields mean absolute error (MAE) around 10<sup>-3</sup> on **both** training and validation set, which looks quite suspicious as the model doesn't have any drop-out or regularization to prevent overfitting. On the other hand, feeding numpy arrays right in gives training MAE around 0.1 and validation MAE around 1.

The low MAE of tf.data.Dataset method looks super suspicious however I just couldn't figure out anything wrong with the code. Also I could confirm the **number of training batches is 200 and validation batches is 50**, meaning I didn't use the training set for validation.

I tried to vary the global random seed or use some different shuffle seeds, which didn't change the results much. Training was done on NVIDIA V100 GPUs, and I tried **tensorflow version 2.9, 2.10, 2.11** which didn't make much difference.

Comment: Use `take()` and `skip()` methods before the shuffling.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the default behaviour of **"shuffle"** method of `tf.data.Dataset`, more specificially the `reshuffle_each_iteration` argument which is by default `True`. Meaning if I implement the following code:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features, labels))
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=2000)
dataset = dataset.batch(8)

train_dataset = dataset.take(200)
val_dataset = dataset.skip(200)

model.fit(train_dataset, validation_data=val_dataset, batch_size=8, epochs=1000)
```

The **dataset would actually be shuffle after each epoch** though it might not look so apparently so. As a result, the **validation data would leak into training set** (in fact there would be no distinguish between these two sets as the order is shuffled every epoch).

So make sure to set `reshuffle_each_iteration` to `False` if you would like to shuffle the dataset and then do train-val split.

UPDATE: TensorFlow confirms this [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/59279) and warning would be added in future docs.

PS: It's a hard lesson for me, as I have been using the model for analysing the results for several months (as a graduating MPhil student).